# How do I step through points of a shape in sketch app?

Tags: sketchapp

Edit Mode: 
Stepping through points allows to select points that have same cooordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Found it! 
Thanks to Peter Nowell: https://medium.com/sketch-app/mastering-the-bezier-curve-in-sketch-4da8fdf0dbbb

> When editing a shape, you can select the next vector point along the
>   path by hitting “tab” on the keyboard. “Shift” + “tab” will select the
>   previous point along the path. Whether the “next point” goes clockwise
>   or counterclockwise around your shape depends on the shape’s direction